# Parse error code 428

Tags: parse-platform

Since April I got a lot of errors with message `Please reach us at migration@parse.com` and code=428

What's up with parse? There are no code 428 at the list of codes.

Comment: You need to migrate your database. See comment here: 
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1639#issuecomment-215231644

Comment: @JeremyPlease could you move your comment to answer so I will be able to accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to migrate your database. See comment here:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1639#issuecomment-215231644